# What is the difference between simple histogram and histogram LBP?

Tags: terminology, histogram, image-processing, intuition, computer-vision

What is the difference between a simple histogram and a histogram LBP (local binary pattern)? Can someone provide the intuition behind histogram LBP?

Answer (score 3):

I have read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) for LBP and decided that they are using the word "histogram" incorrectly. They should really be referring to "binning". The former does "binning" as a pre-processing step, but the [etymology of histogram](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/what-is-the-derivation-of-the-statistical-term-histogram) suggests that it is only appropriate to call a *graph* which depicts *frequencies* using *vertical columns* a histogram.

The LBP is a rudimentary unsupervised classifier. It uses quadrants to bin and calculates local frequency maxima using nearest neighbor. All of these processes could be modified using other more sophisticated ML techniques.

EDIT: It looks like images can be further processed and indeed represented with some kind of histogram like [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Local_Binary_Patterns). It basically serves to graphically represent the features of an image, presumably if it's adequately normalized the bars should represent the intensity/darkness of various cells in the binned graphic. Each 2-D grid member is mapped (in a serpentine fashion) to the 1-D "feature" axis and the corresponding frequency is displayed. I haven't worked with this much, but I imagine the steps necessary to adequately normalize pictures "in the wild" would be impossible.

Comment: +1 that binning alone does not define a histogram. And you're right about the etymology. But in many subjects there is no problem about histograms being presented as _horizontal_ columns (bars, if you will). Whenever the variable is altitude or depth below surface, as is common in the Earth and environmental sciences, that widely appeals as a natural and congenial display.

Comment: @NickCox you're right. I would never disagree with conventions that make sense in a particular discipline. For instance, in marine sciences aquatic depth (usually an independent variable) is often depicted as a Y axis variable is presented in the negative... appearing like you're diving underwater.